Puppeteer Automation: Interacting with dynamically updated elements on a page
I am creating automation for someone to pay bills of multiple people using this automation (url : text
First two steps works fine
on third step, where it needs to enter into form, it is not able to do so. (on next page, when "Next" is pressed, payment form appears dynamically without going to any new url and that results in puppeteer not updating the html to parse)
to help:
on first page select mobile number (9206600733) and zip (54956) and continue
on second page : select other and enter 1 and next
on third page i want to enter card details into this form and am not able to do (and i get:
TimeoutError: Waiting for selector #i4go_cardholderName failed: Waiting failed: 10000ms exceeded, even if i make the wait 100000, it still gives timout error)
even though visually i see that form is loaded and page isn't in loading mode either
await page.goto('https://www1.cellcom.com/quikPay.html', { timeout: 60000 }); // Increase timeout to 60 seconds

            if (userInput === '1') {
                await page.click('#radAccountNumber');
                await page.type('#accountNumber', mainInput);
            } else if (userInput === '2') {
                await page.click('#radMobileNumber');
                await page.type('#mobileNumber', mainInput);
            }

            // Input zip code
            await page.type('#zipcode', zip);
            await page.click('#submitButton');

            await page.waitForNavigation({timeout:60000});


            // Select radio button with ID specifiedAmount
            await page.click('#specifiedAmount');
            // Enter "1" into input field with ID specifiedTextBox
            await page.type('#specifiedTextBox', '1');
            await sleep(1000);
            // Press the "Next" button
            await page.click('.button.mb15.mt15.payment');

            await sleep(12000);

            await page.waitForSelector("#i4go_cardholderName",{timeout:10000})

            await page.type('#i4go_cardholderName', cardDetails[0]);

            await page.select('#i4go_cardType', cardDetails[1]);

            await page.type('#cardNumber', cardDetails[2]);

            await page.select('#i4go_expirationMonth', cardDetails[3]);

            await page.select('#i4go_expirationYear', cardDetails[4]);

            await page.type('#cvv2Code', cardDetails[5]);

            await page.type('#i4go_postalCode', cardDetails[6]);

            await page.click('#i4go_submit');

I have tried:

Waiting for selectors: We attempted to wait for specific selectors to appear on the page after clicking the "Next" button, expecting Puppeteer to detect and interact with the dynamically added elements. However, this approach didn't work because the HTML content accessed by Puppeteer remained unchanged despite visual updates on the page.
Waiting for navigation: We tried waiting for navigation events after clicking the "Next" button, assuming that the page might navigate to a new URL where we could interact with the updated elements. Unfortunately, since the page didn't navigate to a new URL, this approach also failed.
Updating HTML content: We experimented with updating the HTML content using Puppeteer's evaluate function, hoping to modify the page's HTML to include the dynamically added elements. However, this approach didn't produce the desired outcome as it didn't reflect the visual changes made to the page.


I can't get past the first page without credentials. In general, avoid sleeps and check your click nav race condition.
